# ImportError: No module named request, but in Path

Tags: python

I am trying to run a `.py` script that calls the `request` library.

```
anyoung@ANYOUNG-LTW7 /cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/test/temp/Image-Crawler
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

For some reason, Python is unable to find the library. However, I check that the path includes `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
anyoung@ANYOUNG-LTW7 /cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/test/temp/Image-Crawler
$ python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecdsa-0.13-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python27.zip
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-cygwin
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/anyoung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
```

`/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` shows the `request` dir:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

**-- UPDATE BASED ON FIRST ANSWER --**

I installed Python 3. But the module is still not found.

In `cmd.exe`:
C:\Users\anyoung>pip3 install requests

```
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8
a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9
1kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 152kB/s
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b648
7b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133
kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 216kB/s
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1
af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 208kB/s
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5
e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133k
B)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 261kB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975f
c916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
(150kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 407kB/s
Installing collected packages: chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests
  The script chardetect.exe is installed in 'c:\users\anyoung\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warn
ing, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.7 requests-2.19.1
urllib3-1.23
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

I add `c:\users\anyoung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts` to the PATH variable via the GUI:

[image]

Try again and get the same error message:

```
anyoung@ANYOUNG-LTW7 /cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/test/temp/Image-Crawler
$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: try `from urllib import request`. request is not a submodule/subdirectory of urllib.

Comment: `cygdrive`? You're in cygwin? Sounds like you might be using different Python installs in Cygwin and outside of it.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, I am in cygwin. That sounds interesting. `$ which python` gives `/usr/bin/python` for Cygwin. I try the same in `cmd` but it doesn't find anything. I also have an Anaconda installation.

Comment: Why are you doing `pip3 install requests`? `urllib.request` and `requests` have nothing to do with each other. Just because two things have kind of similar names doesn't mean they're the same thing. Does `main.py` really import both of them? If so, you probably need to show us that code, because that's a pretty weird thing to do.

Comment: Also, when you're using Cygwin, you need to be careful to distinguish Cygwin from native. The Cygwin `$PATH` environment variable prepends stuff to the native `Path` environment variable (not to mention only reading `Path` when Cygwin first starts up). And then you seem to be using a native Python installation from within cmd, but possibly a Cygwin Python installation from within Cygwin; if you've installed Python both ways, they're going to have entirely independent site-packages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`request` and `requests` are not the same thing.

`urllib.request` is not the same as either.

Just because two things have kind of similar names doesn’t mean they’re interchangeable. `requests` is a third-party package for doing HTTP at a high level. `urllib.request` is a module in the `urllib` package in the Python 3 standard library for doing HTTP, FTP, and other protocols at a lower level.

The problem here is that you’re trying to run Python 3 code that uses `urllib.request`, in Python 2.7. You can rename every reference to `urllib.request` to its rough Python 2 equivalent, `urllib2`, and that *might* work. But it might not. And there’s a good chance that the code has other Python 3-specific imports or features, so it still won’t run, or won’t run correctly.

The right thing to do is to run the Python 3 code in Python 3.

If you can’t do this, you need to look into porting the code back to Python 2, or to dual-version code using `six` or `modernize`. The `3to2` tool can help get you started, but it won’t do everything for you automatically, and it’s not something people can tell you how to do in a simple Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with my new attempt based on your response, but still failed.